# SQL Query to get country_name and count of occurrences when another column is like input

Tags: mysql

I have 4 MySQL tables `trial`:

```
 nct_id, Primary key
 off_title, could be null
 brief_title could be null
```

and `country`, `condition`, `mesh_term`:

```
 nct_id, foreign key
 country_name or cond or term -> not NULL
```

I want to write an SQL query that finds:

The countries and number of occurrences (with count) when `off_title` or `brief_title` or `cond` or `term` is like a specific input.

I have tried this query but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT country_name , count(*) as cnt
FROM `country` c join `trials` t on c.nct_id = t.nct_id  join `condition` co on c.nct_id=co.nct_id join `mesh_term` mt on c.nct_id =mt.nct_id
WHERE off_title LIKE  "%someinput%" or brief_title LIKE  "%someinput%" or term LIKE "%someinput%" or cond LIKE "%someinput%"
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

The answer I get for count is way bigger than the expected one, so there must be a mistake in the from clause.

To visualize it, if there is a `trial` that has 2 `conditions` that both are like the input then I want the query to return the `country_name` and the `count(*)`. In this case , I except the `count` to be 1 not 2 because they are refering to the same `nct_id`.

Comment: Can you post some example data so we can visualise what you're trying to achieve with this, thanks

Comment: Your query references `official_title`; the schema defines `off_title` — please edit your question for consistency.  Then flag this comment 'no longer needed'.

Comment: Suggestion: prefix each column name with the relevant table alias (`c`, `t`, `co`, `mt`).  Even though SQL doesn't require it, I think it makes it easier for human readers to see what's going on.  I'm a little surprised that you're treating `country` rather than `trials` as the table everything joins to, but since the joins are all equality joins on the same column, it doesn't (shouldn't) actually matter.

Comment: @Martin Let's say there is a `trial` that has 2 `conditions` and both are like the input. What I want is for it to return the `country_name` and the `count` , where the count has to be 1 and not 2 because it's refering to the same `trial`.

Comment: @JimRoussis please **edit** and update your question to show this

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in "where" clause (if I get right the question) try this:

```
WHERE off_title LIKE "%someinput%" AND (brief_title LIKE "%someinput%" or term LIKE "%someinput%" or cond LIKE "%someinput%")
```

If u need at least 2 conditions u will need an "and" or maybe play a little with "XOR" operators